Using Jenkins build a Maven project , the artifact is not latest
I use Jenkins to build a Maven Project.
Jenkins pull the lastest code from Gitlab (show on the console. I confirm it is.) ,but the build artifact is not lastest(i got a wrong JAR at target directory).
Before build the project , i clean the Jenkins workspace ,and run Maven as clean package.
I even saw output on console (maven has build the module jar and transfer it to target dir ),like this:
git checkout -f cecb0029c3332dceaf72527cfe60fb6ca81ced68 # the lastest version  
...
17:17:36 [INFO] --- jar:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ ar-refactoring ---
17:17:36 [INFO] Building jar: /root/.jenkins/workspace/es/jeeplus-modules/ar-refactoring/target/ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar
...

17:18:35 [JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/es/jeeplus-modules/ar-refactoring/target/ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar to org.jeeplus/ar-refactoring/1.0.14-SNAPSHOT/ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar
...



Maybe useful information:

Aim of Maven project is a JAR , and it use Java Modules.
Code need to update at ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar.
Maven use the default repo (/root/.m2/repository)
Before build , i confirm that no ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar anywhere (use find / -name ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar )
Maven version : Apache Maven 3.9.8



I try to clean Jenkins workspace before build , not work


force Jenkins to clone HEAD branch , and also delete the target directory. Make sure maven will not use the .jar previously build.


Use mvn clean package instand of package , not work


make sure maven will not use the .jar previously build.


I go to the Jenkins workspace, download the JAR (artifact of project). It's a wrong JAR. Then run mvn clean package (use the same Maven and JDK )  ,artifact is right!


Now, we found something is going wrong around Jenkins execute clean package. (pom.xml is okay ,maven version is okay , compile order is okay  )



How do you know that  .../target/ar-refactoring-1.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar is not the latest (of commit cecb0029...)? 2. You're using the latest Maven 3.9.8 but a Maven JAR plugin version 3.2.0 from Oct 2019? I`d try it with the latest v3.4.2.



I transfer the artifact to anthor directory and run it ( java -jar ... ) , we use it to be a Test Server. After update,we found the function is not expected.  I download the JAR and use Bandizip to unzip it , decompilation .class File with IDEA. Finally , .class File is not the lastest. 2. Well , there is only some other unimportant warn output on Console with Maven 3.9.8.  And I will try it with lower version. Thanks


I have successfully compiled the project on my development computer using Maven 3.9.8 , it works well. I think the version of Maven is not critical.

does your Jenkins also run mvn clean package for the build? You didn't post your Jenkins Job, maybe you can add this.

and for step 3: did you clean any "leftover" old JAR files from the folder where you download your file to?

Just guessing here, but mvn clean only cleans the working directory .class and artifacts. package creates the jar/war in the target directory.  install, as mentioned in an answer, copies that to the local repo (and deploy to the remote). But to clean/purge artifacts from the local repo, you need to mvn dependency:purge-local-repository (link). Depending what you use to copy the artifact, it may be the one from the local repo, not the new one. Post your steps to know.

does your Jenkins also run mvn clean package for the build  Yes, It is.  I saw the clean log output on Console

The question is not very clear of what is happening and what is supposed to be happening. Do you get the wrong jar file in the target directory? Or isn't the jar file visible by other Maven projects as it is not in /root/.m2/repository?
To have Maven put the jar file in /root/.m2/repository, you will have to use "mvn install" instead of "mvn package". "mvn package" only creates the jar file in the target directory.
If you have access to the server on which Jenkins runs, you can log in to the jenkins account using a shell and then go to the workspaces directory and the directory of your project (/root/.jenkins/workspace/es/jeeplus-modules/ar-refactoring) and then can initiate the build by hand and inspect the resulting project structure to debug your problem.

yeah, I get the wrong Jar file in the target directory.
